# Washing machine trips Gfi when rinse cycle starts

Tags: appliances

Washing machine trips GFI as soon as rinse cycle starts.

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Answer (score 1):

Your washer has a ground-fault, or the GFCI is bad.  Replace the GFCI, have the washer serviced, or don't plug the washer into a GFCI receptacle.